# customize Java dialog Color, Appearance, Theme

Tags: java, dialog

I want to make Java JDialog appear like it is presented in the image (link below) using JDK 6 Swing. Is it possible? if so kindly guide me.
Image Link:
[Image](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_AnzmYq61hHI/S8RTAznktKI/AAAAAAAAAW0/c4HVCuchdjc/s1600-h/saveConfiguration%5B2%5D.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java swing this is called the 'look and feel'. You can change the look and feel as follows:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Sun has a large [Look and feel tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) that explains how this works.

I'm not sure which look and feel you are linking to though, you'd have to find that out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible.
You can add your component is,

```
  myDialog.getContentPane().add(someComponent);
```

and the color is,

```
   myDialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color."YourColor");
```

and select the theme, and set into to your main program like,

```
   nimbus, motif,windows,etc
```

Then the selected look and feel will be chang your theme.